# Is it possible to read an external resource file which is not embedded in application?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, embedded-resource

Is it possible to read an external resource file which is not embedded in an application?

I am using Delphi 7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To read directly a [res file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648007%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you must parse the  [RESOURCEHEADER structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648027%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then read each resource in the file depending of its type. If you want avoid writing this type of code yourself, then you can use the [`Delphi Resource Utilities`](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d7resourceutils.htm) from Colin Wilson (author of the [`XN Resource Editor`](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm) tool).